# Application can't access /home/user/

Tags: xubuntu

I'm fairly new user of Xubuntu.
For few days now, when I try to list the content of the folder /home/user/ through an app file browser, I just can't list this specific folder content. 
Any other folder is fine, but if I click on this particular one, in the best case it just wait for ever unti lI chose another one, but most of the time, the app freezes and has to be killed.

Any other subfolder or drive is ok.

What could be the reason and how to solve that?

According to the different comments below I tried the following:

I tried with 2 different apps, having different behaviour: I opened both Blender and Gedit from command line. Blender simply freeze and has to be killed, while Gedit just wait forever, but I still can access another folder. None of them have a message appearing in the terminal windows. –

There is no error log related to this issue. I tried with 3 different apps, crashed the 3 while accessing the Personal Folder, but no log appear. The last ones of the list in /var/log/ are auth.log, wtmp, and syslog, all at a time way before the crash of the apps.

There is no problem accessing the Personal folder /home/user/ with Thunar.

It seems this issue is also preventing me to launch some app: for example, I can't launch Filezilla anymore. It stays stuck at "Reading locale option from /home/user/.config/filezilla/filezilla.xml".

(But from time to time Thunar has a strange behavior. It doesn't seems to be directly related to the above problme but who knows?: Sometimes Thunar crashes and freeze. I have to kill it, and then it's impossible to relaunch it. In the command line, I got the following error: "Failed to register: Le délai d’attente est dépassé".
Then it's impossible to relaunch Thunar. Even by trying to killall, or whatever, I have to reboot. Except sudo Thunar, then it launches, but that's not really a solution. )

Another simple test: 
I open a terminal, then simply list the folder:

```
user@user-linux:~$ ls
```

returns nothing.
sudo ls works.

cd anyfolder, then ls gives me my folder tree and files.

Thank you

Mx

Comment: What is "app file browser"?

Comment: "the app freezes and has to be killed. " find the reason. Generally: start the app from command line and when it crashes see what the error is. Otherwise you probably need to check contents of /var/log/ and then the file in there that was updated LAST (so `ls -ltr` and then the bottom one after you have the app crashed) Please edit the question with the results. From what we have now it will be impossible to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: Hello, sorry, Englsih is not my native language. By "app file browser" I mean the windows that pop up when you want to open a file. There is a kind of file browser that appears, with the folder tree and files, in which you can navigate for finding your location and file.

Comment: I opened both Blender and Gedit from command line. Blender simply freeze and has to be killed, while Gedit just wait forever, but I still can access another folder. None of them have a message appearing in the terminal windows.

Comment: There is no error log related to this issue. I tried with 3 different apps, crashed the 3 while accessing the Personal Folder, but no log appear. The last ones of the list in /var/log/ are auth.log, wtmp, and syslog, all at a time way before the crash of the apps.

Comment: Edit your question to add any information that can help identify the issue. Can you see the contents of the problem folder with the file manager (Thunar in Xubuntu)?

Comment: @user1037346 if no errors are shown it might be time to start a memory check from the grub menu :) Random crashes mostly are caused by faulty memory.

Comment: Are you using two different users or just one?

Comment: Just one user. I checked the folder permissions, they're all the same